# signalr connection event handle in java android

Tags: java, android, sockets, signalr

I'm using SignalR to make a two-player online game. So far so good. But when one of the players' internet is cut off ( in a few milliseconds) or the server is cut off for any reason, the program no longer works. How can I be notified of connection events?
How can I reconnect automatically?

I have been researching it for a long time, but I have not found a solution

Asp.NET core 5.0 server-side:

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        LogHelper logHelper = new LogHelper("hub");

        public async Task Move(float x, float y)
        {
                await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceivePosition", x, y);
        }
}
```

client-side java android studio :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "qazwsx";
    Button btnStart;
    View viewMove;

    HubConnection hubConnection;

    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "CheckResult"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://192.168.1.10:45455/notification").build();

        hubConnection.on("ReceivePosition", (x, y) -> {

            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                viewMove.setX(x);
                viewMove.setY(y);

                Log.i(TAG, String.format("onCreate: x:%s  y:%s", x, y));
            });

        }, Float.class, Float.class);

        btnStart = findViewById(R.id.bntStart);
        viewMove = findViewById(R.id.viewMove);


        btnStart.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate > btnStart.setOnClickListener > status:" + hubConnection.getConnectionState());
            if (btnStart.getText().toString().equals("START")) {
                if (hubConnection.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.DISCONNECTED) {
                    btnStart.setText("STOP");
                }
            } else {
                if (hubConnection.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                    hubConnection.stop();

                }
            }
        });

        final float[] dX = new float[1];
        final float[] dY = new float[1];
        viewMove.setOnTouchListener((view, event) -> {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                //this is your code
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    dX[0] = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    dY[0] = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    view.animate()
                            .x(event.getRawX() + dX[0])
                            .y(event.getRawY() + dY[0])
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                    if (hubConnection.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                        hubConnection.send("Move", event.getRawX() + dX[0], event.getRawY() + dY[0]);
                        Log.i(TAG, String.format("move: x:%s  y:%s", dX[0], dY[0]));

                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;

        });
    }


}
```

Comment: If internet is off you can not get any event from the User .. You can use a ping mechanism lets say if u don't get a ping in like 30 seconds you can assume the user is offline . And this goes for both parties including the signaling Server . For reconnection i am sure there r callbacks for connection status form where you try reconnecting again once the connection lost . There might be some build in mechanism also check the docs . Disclaimer - i never used `SignalR`.

Comment: @ADM thankyou, By disconnection, I mean disconnecting the note in a few milliseconds and reconnecting, but the signal is no longer reconnected. And it can not be handled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, I managed to solve this problem. I am writing the solution to this problem. I hope it solves someone else's problem

**handle the signalr connection close:**

```
hubConnection.onClosed(exception -> {
            //do something
            //attemt to connect
            //note: exception is null when the user stop connection
        });
```

**handle the signalr connection start:**

```
    hubConnection.start()
                            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground > doOnError: ", throwable);
//start fail , try again    
//note: the start function need try chach when we use this function
                            })
                            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                                Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground > doOnComplete.");
                                //start complated
                            })
                            .blockingAwait();//you must write this function ,else other function not worck
```